# selenium webdriver url navigation (on microsoft edge with window10) , hang after 28/29th url

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have been doing URL navigation ( list of URL in a file ) using selenium webdriver for microsoft edge browser on window 10 machine.
I have written automation script in python.

code snippet :

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
for url in list_of_url: #100 url
print "navigating url :",url
driver.get(url)
```

So after navigating 28th url, Script got hanged on 29th URL on "driver.get(url)" line ,and never return.
I have also tried with different list of urls, the behavior is same, got hanged on 29th url.

Pls look into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Edge browser standalone server. Download it from [WebDriver for Microsoft Edge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt188085(v=vs.85).aspx), and place it in the same directory where the scripts are stored.

Try the code snippet below, working fine for me -

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

# create new Edge session
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
edge_path = dir + "\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(edge_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.freelancer.in/")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("LandingHeader-authBtn")
login_button.click()
```